# Quadcopter with wind effect

Tags: quadcopter

I drawn the Simulink model of a quadcopter with virtual joystick input and now I want to add the wind but I am little bit confused how to add wind with that model. actually my model is like that input joystick to the rotational+ translational  and get output from 3d Animation. I add wind model to my rotational sub model my but some one says like you can not add x,y and z component to the pitch , roll and yaw. so I trying to add this wind with thrust force like toque along x direction add with wind x component and torque y with wind y component and torque z with wind z component but still I think there is problem in units like I am adding force with velocity so its not make sense. I saw some paper in which wind is added like force and momentum component but I am not clear with that idea , can anyone help how should I connect wind component and why should I add momentum and force component???

Comment: What sort of wind modelling are you doing? A uniform wind will behave as a moving reference frame, but buffeting or turbulence needs a different approach.

Comment: The question needs clarification, normally, the wind is added to the true air speed of the simulation model. But in your case, the airspeed is probably not a factor in the simulation. Hence the difficulty.

Comment: I wanna add the wind as a component of force and momentum I want to know what should be force component and wind component may I add to Euler equation ?
Komal

Comment: Pete kirkham I want to add turbalance wind like constant + white noise wind but I don't know how to add in my simulink model and what should be the component of force and wind added into translational and rotational part in order to visualize the wind effect ??? Komal

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10361)

Comment: This is I want to know it's not different question. In my post I try to say like which method I did to add wind but I was not successed.  And now I review some literature review I got a concept to add with you have to add momentum and force component and I want to know what the component should be ?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10361)

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Komal/user19839. On Stack exchange *answers* need to answer the question. If you need to clarify your question you should edit it rather than add an answer.

Comment: It looks like you may have accidentally created two accounts (Komal & user19839). Stack Exchange only allows an individual to actively use one account, so please follow the instructions at [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)
Note that moderators [can't merge accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272251) for you, but may delete accounts they believe to be [sock puppets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/138432).